# can't decode dataview of arraybuffers js objects to JSON using web bluetooth API

Tags: javascript, bluetooth-lowenergy, gatt, arraybuffer, web-bluetooth

When I run below code and it gives DataView objects which contains arraybuffers. I know Array buffers are encoded data so we need to decode them using the encoded reverse mechanism to view data.
When BLE device is connected and gives data it prints console

Tractor tester // device name
but all other 3 fields it prints boxes []>[] like this, [] looks like an array but its a complete box shape **not an array**

please help

```
async function onConnect() {
    
      try {
    
        console.log('Requesting any Bluetooth Device...');
        const device = await navigator.bluetooth.requestDevice({
          acceptAllDevices: true,
          optionalServices: ['generic_access']
        });
    
        console.log('Connecting to GATT Server...');
        const server = await device.gatt.connect();
    
        console.log('Getting Service...');
        const service = await server.getPrimaryService('generic_access');
    
        console.log('Getting Characteristics...');
        const characteristics = await service.getCharacteristics();
    
        for (const characteristic of characteristics) {
          switch (characteristic.uuid) { // characteristic.uuid
    
            case '00002a00-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb': // device name
              await readValue1(characteristic);
              break;
    
            case '00002a01-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb': // Appearance
              await readAppearanceValue2(characteristic);
              break;
    
            case '00002a04-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb': // Manufacturer Name String
              await readValue3(characteristic);
              break;
    
            case '00002aa6-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb':
              await readValue4(characteristic); // Central Address Resolution
              break;
    
            default: console.log('Unknown Characteristic: ' + characteristic.uuid);
          }
        }
    
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
      }
    
      async function readValue1(characteristic) {
    
        const value = await characteristic.readValue();
        $('#dataset1').text(new TextDecoder().decode(value));
        console.log(new TextDecoder().decode(value));
      }
    
      async function readAppearanceValue2(characteristic) {
    
        const value = await characteristic.readValue();
        $('#dataset2').text(new TextDecoder().decode(value));
        console.log(new TextDecoder().decode(value));
      }
    
      async function readValue3(characteristic) {
    
        const value = await characteristic.readValue();
        $('#dataset3').text(new TextDecoder().decode(value));
        console.log(new TextDecoder().decode(value));
      }
    
      async function readValue4(characteristic) {
    
        const value = await characteristic.readValue();
        $('#dataset4').text(new TextDecoder().decode(value));
        console.log(new TextDecoder().decode(value));
      }
    
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the characteristic values are text? They may be numerical values. You can wrap an ArrayBuffer in a Uint8Array to extract individual bytes or use a DataView to extract more complex fields.

Do you have documentation from the device manufacturer for the format of the data provided? Without it some reverse engineering is required.